# Is the determinant a scale factor for any shape?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant

My linear algebra text states that the determinant of a matrix A is always the scaling factor that you will get by left multiplying a coordinate matrix B by A. But the only examples they give are triangles and squares. Is this true regardless of the shape described by B? Even if it's not regular, not convex, intersects with itself, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. One way to see this is to divide your shape into triangles. Since $A$ scales each triangle by the same factor (namely, $\det A$) it will scale the entire shape described by $B$ by this factor too.

Comment: This isn't quite right, or at least it doesn't tell the full story. The determinant does not scale the volume of a set that does not have volume in the first place. (There are sets that don't have volume.) Certainly the set doesn't have to be regular or convex, but it can't be too pathological.

Comment: True, but since he described his shape via a "coordinate matrix" B, not only does it have volume, it is in fact a polygon.

Comment: That's fair: I neglected the end of the sentence "regardless of the shape **described by $B$"**; I was answering the title question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on your definition of volume.

In an introductory analysis class, we typically define the volume of a set $A$ lying in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $E$ by the integral $\int_A|dV|$, where $|dV|$ is the Euclidean density and $\int$ is the Riemann integral. (This definition of volume is called the "content" or the "Jordan measure" of the set $A$.) If you perform a linear transformation $L$ on $E$, then the volume of the image of $A$, i.e. the volume of $L(A)$, is $\int_{L(A)}|dV|$. (It turns out that if $A$ has volume according to this definition, then $L(A)$ must have volume, too.)

But by the key step in the proof of the multivariable change of variables theorem, $\int_{L(A)}|dV|=\int_A|\det L|\,|dV|$.

Therefore $\text{Vol}(L(A))=|\det L|\cdot\text{Vol}(A)$, assuming that $A$ has volume in the first place.

Your book focuses on the case of triangles and squares because linear algebra isn't analysis. But to answer your question, you must do some analysis in order to get precise about what you mean by the volume of an arbitrarily shaped subset of a Euclidean space.

Comment: (This is an answer to the title question, about arbitrary "shapes." For shapes described by a coordinate matrix, the argument is the same -- the change of variables theorem for linear transformations -- but in that case we don't have to add a caveat about non-measurable sets.)